# Redirect url to the CDN storage

Tags: nginx, redirect, cdn

I have structure folders on my nginx server:
Image URL

> https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/image.jpg
>
> https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/WP-data/data/employees/per-005/9032.jpg

I want it redirect to my CDN and get the picture on that CDN all time..

> https://cdn.example.com/image.jpg
>
> https://cdn.example.com/WP-data/data/employees/per-005/9032.jpg

I try to use with this setting but it doesn't work.

```
location ~ ^(/wp-content/themes|/wp-content/uploads)/.*\.(jpe?g|gif|css|png|js|ico|pdf|m4a|mov|mp3)$ {
             rewrite ^ http://cdn.example.com$request_uri?
             permanent;
             access_log off;
      }
```

Comment: You should replace the URLs in your content, not issue 301 redirects. You are adding one extra request to the flow with the 301 redirect, which decreases the benefit of having a CDN.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to ServerFault!

In order to remove `/wp-content/uploads` (and `/wp-content/themes`) and redirect the resulting URL to a CDN, the following code should work...

```
location ~ ^(/wp-content/themes|/wp-content/uploads)(?'short_url'/.*\.(jpe?g|gif|css|png|js|ico|pdf|m4a|mov|mp3))$ {
     return 301 http://cdn.example.com$short_url;
     access_log off;
}
```

This uses "named capture" method while evaluating a regular expression. There is no need of `rewrite` statement as we already had a regular expression in `location`. Nginx supports named captures using the following syntax:

```
?<name>     Perl 5.10 compatible syntax, supported since PCRE-7.0
?'name'     Perl 5.10 compatible syntax, supported since PCRE-7.0
?P<name>    Python compatible syntax, supported since PCRE-4.0
```